# O plugin Advanced Custom Fields funciona em Localhost mas na Hospedagem não

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme, plugin-wordpress

Fiz meu tema em Localhost e utilizei o plugin Advanced Custom Fields, tudo ok.

Quando envio para o servidor o tema, instalo o plugin Advanced Custom Fields, o botão "Criar Campos" não funciona e não consigo criar os campos que fiz no localhost.

Veja -

**1. Em Localhost:**

[image: **inserir a descrição da imagem aqui**]

**2. Na hospedagem:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Quando clico em "Criar Campos" não acontece nada.**

Temtei exportar mas na hora de importar diz que não existe nenhum arquivo, mas existe sim.

Não sei o que pode estar errado, já que tudo que está em localhost está na hospedagem.

Meu console do navegador mostra:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed, version 1.4.1
acf-input.min.js:2 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
select2.full.min.js:3 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
acf-field-group.min.js?ver=5.7.12:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
    at acf-field-group.min.js?ver=5.7.12:1
    at acf-field-group.min.js?ver=5.7.12:1
post.php?post=72&action=edit:1150 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
    at post.php?post=72&action=edit:1150
post.php?post=72&action=edit:1154 Uncaught ReferenceError: acf is not defined
    at post.php?post=72&action=edit:1154
2/wp-admin/post.php?post=72&action=edit#:1 Unchecked runtime.lastError: The message port closed before a response was received.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoje, dia 13/05/2019 lançaram uma atualização e voltou a funcionar....